# Is there software to capture and view raw MIDI data coming from a controller?

Tags: software, midi, osx

This is partially out of curiosity, and partly, potentially, useful.

The gist of what I'm looking for is an application (preferably OSX, though it wouldn't be a deal breaker to be Windows or *nix, and preferably free) that would capture MIDI controller data as it entered the computer, whether that be SysEx, channel, system, controller, note on/off, pots, you name it. **All** of it.

I'm not terribly concerned with the format that the data would be presented.  I'm sure it would be interesting however it was presented.  I picture, basically, a window that fills up with text (midi data) as I send data through.  My guess would be that it parsed out whatever OSX's core Midi software saw.

I am not interested in a large piece of software that "also does MIDI", or has some extra small feature amongst the DAW backdrop.  Looking for a small footprint.

tl;dr, The last time I had all of my gear set up, my keyboard controller (an [Alesis Q25](http://alesis.com/q25)) kept throwing pitch bend data on its own.  I was sure that the data stopped when the controller was unplugged, but I had no way of pinning down exactly what was going on.  I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [MIDIMonitor](http://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) will do what you want.

Comment: Yep, I think that's exactly what I want :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this also. That's the great thing about the SE network, even after OP has his/her answer, there is useful information for future users.

Answer (score 3):

A Windows alternative would be MIDI-OX.  Solid stuff.

http://www.midiox.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Pure Data](http://puredata.info/) is an extremely powerful piece of freeware designed and coded by the creator of MAX/MSP.

I've used it a number of times to create powerful midi controlled synthesizers which you can build and fully customize yourself.

Comment: I was about to recommend PD myself, but the asker specifically indicated that he didn't want a larger system that "also does MIDI".

Comment: I appreciate that, but keep in mind with Pd you're free to build a patch with only a functionality you want :)